# How to change the format and content of headings in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document with headings already and I wish to change the format of one heading. (Imagine the heading is Chapter x and I want to make it Capitulo x) How can you do that?

Now before someone tells me "google it" I have already done it and got for example [this](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-heading-styles-ms-word-53997.html) or [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-or-create-new-styles-in-word-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563) Problem is that does not work at all. 
It says how to change the style but not the text.

Currently I have right clicked the heading style and I got this (sorry not english)

[image: headings]

I want to change that "1章" to "Chapter 1" 
Where can I find the text of this?

Comment: There are several ways to change the format, but I assume you need the heading to remain associated with the heading style for purposes like TOC?

Comment: I have tried and so far no success. I need the number to change : 1,2,3, but the Ch. to remain. I could not change the format so I tried to create a new one but again no sucess

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to change the appearance without changing the association with the heading style, so that things like TOC and numbering aren't affected?

Comment: I just need to translate the "章" to "Ch." (or chapter). The numbers of course have to be as they are. And of course I have to update the TOC to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You can add words (section, Chapter, etc.) to the headings from the "Define New Multilevel list" dialog.

You should set up all of your headings here, assigning them, their indents, leading test, and most important here, giving the "Listnum" field a name value (my example doesn't have one).

Always make change to a heading's indents and tabs here. If you use the paragraph style editor to do so, you'll come to grief when Word blows up your heading formats (learnt via hard lesson).

[image: Multilevel list dialog]